# Prove that $M=E(\sqrt{a-b\sqrt{c}})$ is the minimal Galois extension of $F$ .

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

For a field $F$ such that $char(F)\ne 2$. Consider the tower of extension $E/L/F$ where $L = F(√c)$ and $E = L(\sqrt{a + b\sqrt{c}})$, for some $a,b,c ∈ F$.

Suppose we have $E/F$ is not Galois, I need to prove that $M=E(\sqrt{a-b\sqrt{c}})$ is the minimal Galois extension of $F$ .

Here **minimal** is in the sense that no smaller subﬁeld of $M$ containing $E$ is Galois over $F$.

I have spent some time on the question, so I would really appreciate if someone can give me some explaination. Thanks a lot.

Also I think I need a picture of extensions and correspondence to see it cleae, an reference would also be appreciate, thanks!

Comment: $M$ is quadratic over $E$, so if $M$ is Galois over $F$ and $E$ is not then the minimality is more or less free, no?  What would the Galois group be?  It has order 8.

Comment: @sharding4 Oh maybe I get it. Using the degree of extension... $2$ is the least degree of non-trivial extension...

Comment: @sharding4 Considering the picture, I am trying to find out all the generaters of subextensions.

Comment: @sharding4 I believe that the Galois group is $D_4$.

Comment: Yes.  The Galois Group is the Dihedral Group $D_4$ assuming you have shown $M$ is Galois over $F$.

Comment: Does the fact that $M$ is Galois follows from $M$ is the splitting field of the seperable polynomial $x^4-2ax+a^2-b^c=(x-\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{c}})(x+\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{c}})(x-\sqrt{a-b\sqrt{c}})(x+\sqrt{a-b\sqrt{c}})$?

Comment: Yes.  Being the splitting field of a separable polynomial is one of the equivalent conditions for an extension to be Galois.